# Flask-Mail: how to intercept messages for integration testing

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I want to use Selenium for integration testing. My app sends confirmation message when users register(using Flask-User extension). I would like to intercept a message, extract a link and "click" on it in my test.

But how do I intercept sent emails? I've tried the approach from docs:

```
with mail_engine.record_messages() as outbox:
    assert len(outbox) > 0
```

However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this approach wasn't working because I was using LiveServerTestCase from Flask-Testing.

You can subscribe to signals, BUT LiveServerTestCase than forks the process(so app runs in one process, and testing code in another), so (depending on the time of subscription) the subscriber code won't be called at all or will be called in the separate process. Either way it is not what I wanted.

I found a solution, which isn't very elegant, but works: create a multiprocessing.Queue, subscribe to the signal, and pass all messages back to testing code through the Queue.

Here is the code:

```
class MyTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def create_app(self): # this is called before fork
        app = create_test_app()
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
        self.email_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        email_dispatched.connect(self.message_sent)
        return app

    def message_sent(self, message, app):
        self.email_q.put(message) # simply put it into the queue, will be run in the "app" process

    def test_all(self):
        # here you can do testing, this will be run in the "testing" process
        # and when you need messages do this:
        message = self.email_q.get(timeout=5) # get email from queue. 5 seconds is reasonable timeout, after it we can assume that the mail wasn't sent at all
```